# Log-Normal Distribution Table

Tags: statistics

Please, Sorry moderators, move this where its correspond, where can i find a Log-Normal Distribution Table, similar to [this](https://www.ime.usp.br/~chang/home/mae116/aulas/Aula%206_distribui%E7%E3o%20Normal.pdf)? I looking for this but I do not found yet

Comment: It is on the last page of the pdf (in case anyone doesn't want to look through the whole document).

Comment: Of course, you are entitled to want a standard lognormal table. But most people would not find the need for one, and that's why you're having trouble finding one. From a table of the standard normal distribution, you can find $P(Z  \le 1) = 0.8413;$ if $Y$ is standard lognormal, then $P(Y \le e^1 = e) = 0.8413.$ Similarly, $P(Z \le z) = P(Y \le e^z).$

Answer (score 1):

The following Octave code generates a nicely formatted table of lognormal cdf values for given location and scale parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma > 0$.

```
printf("    | ");
k = 0;
for j = 1:10
    printf("%6.2f  ", k);
    k += 0.01;
end
printf("\n----+-");
for j = 1:9
    printf("--------");
end
printf("------\n");
k = 1;
mu = 0;
sig = 1;
x = 0:0.01:3.99;
for i = 1:length(x)/10
    printf("%3.1f | ", x(k));
    for j = 1:10
        z = logncdf(x(k++), mu, sig);
        printf("%6.4f  ", z);
    end
    printf("\n");
end
```